# Mouse middle button does not work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mouse

i have a gridview which contains a linkbutton with a ID `LnkCourseName`

i have requirement that on a click of Middle button of a mouse a new tab should open.

to check the which button of a mouse got clicked, i used a javascript function as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonalert(event) {

                var button;
                if (event.which == null)
                    button = (event.button < 2) ? leftclickclear() :
                 ((event.button == 4) ? middleclickclear() : rightclickclear());
                else
                    button = (event.which < 2) ? leftclickclear() :
                 ((event.which == 2) ? middleclickclear() : rightclickclear());
                dont(event);

            }
            function leftclickclear() {

                $('#<%=HdUrl.ClientID %>').val("left");



            }
            function rightclickclear() {
                $('#<%=HdUrl.ClientID %>').val("right");


            }
            function middleclickclear() {

                $('#<%=HdUrl.ClientID %>').val("middle");

            }
            function dont(event) {
            if (event.preventDefault)
                event.preventDefault();
            else
                event.returnValue = false;

        }
</script>
```

But on a press of a middle button i get an error

> javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr538$ViewTC_TakeAClass$GrdCourseDetail$ctl02$LnkCourseName','')

on a new tab url. Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be standard behaviour for any reasonable browser, and isn't really an ASP.NET or script issue - the problem is that you're using a link **button**, which will do a postback just like a button (i.e. `<input type=submit>`), and it's not a link as in an default **a** element.

If your links are really just that, and are not expected to post back to the server to execute some logic, and instead just specifies a URL to link to, then use a `HyperLink` control instead.

Comment: Sir i need to execute some logic but on a click of middle button it should redirect to another page.